# Expression tree - not contains

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I need to create an Expression to search one string not contains another. I was able to create it for contains method:

```
return Expression.Call(firstOrDefaultCall, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), Expression.Constant(text));
```

how to convert it to 'not contains'?

Comment: [Logical negation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-negation-operator-)?

Comment: no, see accepted answer, you should use Expression.Not method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would you normally write it?

```
var stringValue = "foo"
var result = !stringValue.Contains("o");
```

Notice the logical negation operator `!` before `Contains()`. That's the only part you are missing. To negate a boolen value when building an expression, use `Expression.Not()`:

```
return Expression.Not(
    Expression.Call(
        firstOrDefaultCall, 
        typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), 
        Expression.Constant(text)));
```

And don't fall into trap of using `Expression.Negate()`. That one is for an arithmetic negation operation, example of arithmetic negation:

```
var negatedPi = Math.PI * -1;
```